# Does php server monitor require a separate server to work properly?

Tags: php, server

I would like to use php server monitor (http://www.phpservermonitor.org) to monitor the uptime of a website.

My question is, can I install php server monitor on the same server that hosts the website I'd like to monitor and have it work effectively? Or does php server monitor need to run on a different server from the website it monitors?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to be most effective, I would say the monitor needs to run on a different server. What happens if the server loses power or a hard drive fails? The web server AND the monitor will stop working, which makes the monitor pointless.

If you don't want to set up another server for this, there are plenty of 3rd party services that will handle this for you. For example, take a look at Uptime Robot (https://uptimerobot.com/) which has a free plan that might meet your requirements. New Relic (http://newrelic.com/) is also good if you're looking for something more advanced.